# Are these 'that'-clauses complements or adjuncts?

Tags: complements, adjuncts

> (1) It's a plan [that is being touted as the most modest proposal considered yet in Congress].

Here, the *that*-clause is a relative clause that modifies the antecedent 'plan', so I believe it's not a complement but an adjunct. (Correct me if I'm wrong.)

**Now, I'm not sure whether the following *that*-clauses are complements or adjuncts:**

> (2) It's unfortunate [that we meet under these circumstances].
>
> (3) I have it on good authority [that you are in charge here].
>
> (4) It's for that reason [that she is currently number one].

In (2) and (3), the *that*-clauses are extraposed, whereas in (4) it's the cleft clause.

Comment: If you could provide a test for identifying complements versus adjuncts, we could do more than give an opinion. And also a test for why it's important to know which one these constructions are.

Comment: @JohnLawler As far as I know, distinguishing one from the other is not subject to change in different types of grammars. So I don't know why I should come up with a test myself. Also, I believe the distinguishing is vital to English grammar, so I guess that's why it's important.

Comment: I don't think it's vital to English grammar. Nothing hinges on it, and if a test can't distinguish it, it's not important enough to care about.

Comment: Integrated (defining) relative clauses are normally modifiers, so the relative clause in (1) is modifying “plan”. Complement and adjunct are quite different functions. Adjuncts are modifiers in clause structure, but relatives are modifiers in NP structure. In (2-3) the _that_ clauses are complements. And the bracketed clause in the cleft (4) is  a relative clause. Btw, I would avoid calling relatives _that_ clauses since the term is widely used for declarative content clauses, like those in (2-3).

Comment: @BillJ Do you mean the cleft clause in (4) is not a complement?

Comment: @JK2 that's right: its a postnucleus.  Btw, to be clearer about (2), the clause is more specifically an extraposed subject, serving as a semantic argument of the VP, (i.e. a type of complement)

Comment: @BillJ If the bracketed clause in (2) is a complement, I don't know why that in (4) isn't one. Although you say the cleft clause is a relative clause, the two are not entirely the same.

Comment: @JK2  The clause in (2) is an extraposed subject, but the one in (4) is a relative clause. Relative clauses are not complements.

Comment: @BillJ How could a relative clause modify a PP (for that reason)? In fact, the meaning of (4) doesn't even support the interpretation that the cleft clause modifies "for that reason".

Comment: @JK2 It doesn't modify anything. The relative clauses that occur in clefts are not modifiers. They do not combine with the antecedent to form a constituent. In your example, "reason she is currently number one" is not a constituent. Which is why I said in my earlier comment that it's a 'postnucleus'.

Comment: @BillJ That's what I'm talking about. The very reason that a relative clause is not a complement is because it's a modifier. So, you cannot say the cleft clause is not a complement simply because it's a relative clause.

Comment: @JK2 Eh? The clause in the cleft is a relative one, but it is neither  a modifier nor a complement.  It's a special kind of relative clause called a postnucleus. That seems perfectly clear to me.

Comment: @BillJ so how exactly would we parse (2)-(4)? Would it be possible for you to expand upon this in an answer? Providing a full analysis of these sentences?

Answer (score 1):

> (2) *It's unfortunate [that we meet under these circumstances].*
>
> (3) *I have it on good authority [that you are in charge here].*
>
> (4) *It's for that reason [that she is currently number one].*

In [2] the bracketed content clause is an extraposed subject. The dummy pronoun "it" serves as subject, and the *that*-clause as extraposed subject. Compare the basic, non-extraposed, version [*That we meet under these circumstances*] *is unfortunate*, where the bracketed content clause is subject.

[3] is also an extraposed construction, but this time it's not the subject that is extraposed, but an internal complement. Here the dummy "it" appears as object and the subordinate clause as extraposed object. The basic, non-extraposed version is inadmissible by virtue of having the subordinate clause located between the verb and another complement: we can't say * *I have that you are in charge here on good authority*.

[4] is trickier than the others. The bracketed element is a relative clause in an *it*-cleft construction. But unlike typical relative clauses, it isn't a dependent of "reason", i.e. it doesn't modify it. The words *reason that she is currently number one* do not form a syntactic constituent. It's for this reason that the relative clause is analysed as a postnucleus, not as a modifier.

Comment: Thanks for putting this in an answer :) But what exactly is a postnucleus? Is it a function? How is it defined? Does it only occur in cleft-sentences? Is it still seen as part of the NP, even though it's neither a modifier nor a complement of the head (in this case _reason_)? In that case, what is the support for that analysis? So many questions :) Would it be possible to explain this in a little more detail?